# Fetching API inside curly braces

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am trying to fetch data inside curly braces but it is not working. I am a student & I don't have much knowledge regarding on API's.

The Result I am trying to get is `89325` in php

```
{"ethereum":{"php":89325}}
```

**What I have tried **

```
    fetch ("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=ethereum&vs_currencies=PHP")
    .then((response) => { return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
    var api =data.php;
    console.log(api);
    })
    .catch();
```

**The Error I am getting:**

[image]

Comment: failed to fetch - sounds like the request is failing - but the code you've shown does not fail in that way - what browser are you doing this on?

Comment: by the way, that `.catch();` is pointless ... do something like `.catch(err => console.log(err));` to handle the error

Comment: Im using google chrome as the browser

Comment: well, the code you've posted does not produce the error you have in the picture - so, can't help

Comment: Here is what I got,, UPdate I add a on the VAR api = data.php;

Comment: VM62:1 GET https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=ethereum&vs_currencies net::ERR_FAILED
(anonymous) @ VM62:1
VM62:8 TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Is `{"ethereum":{"php":89325}}` what is expected, right? Seems the codes console `{"ethereum":{"php":89325}}` on the log. What exactly you want to get as a result?

Comment: I update my Question. I want to get Number on php as the result only 89325

Comment: OH!!! you're doing this from a page loaded using `file:///` protocol - won't work - you'll need http or https server

Comment: @bravo Thanks mate... A sample would be better :D I just search that on youtube..  Not trying to spoonfeed... I just want to know a sample... Still learning to this field...

Comment: when you load your page in your browser ... does it say `file:///` or `http:///`  in the address? if it's `file:///` your code won't work - you'll need a web server to "host" that page so it can access that API

Comment: :D I got it now.. Thanks